# Appearing and Disappearing an array of images

Tags: javascript

I want to make images in assets called Leo + a number appearing and disappearing but it change images when the image is shown the half of the time, I don't understand why, i tried changing milliseconds but nothing

```js
var counterForImages = 0
let leo = $("#Leo")
var photoAppearing = window.setInterval(function(){
  var fadingIn = window.setInterval(function(){
    leo.css("opacity", Number(leo.css("opacity"))+0.02)
    if (leo.css("opacity") == 1) {
      clearInterval(fadingIn)
    }
  }, 25)
  var fadingOut = window.setInterval(function(){
    leo.css("opacity", Number(leo.css("opacity"))-0.02)
    if (leo.css("opacity") == 0) {
      clearInterval(fadingOut)
    }
  }, 25)
  leo.attr("src", "assets/Leo" + counterForImages%3 + ".png")
  if (counterForImages%3 == 0) {
    leo.css("width", "200px")
    leo.css("left", "85%")
  } else if (counterForImages%3 == 1) {
    leo.css("width", "400px")
    leo.css("left", "80%")
  } else if (counterForImages%3 == 2) {
    leo.css("width", "180px")
    leo.css("left", "85%")
  }
  counterForImages++
}, 5000);
```

***UPDATE***
tried the following, does someone know how to avoid maximum recursion depth and do something forever?

```
var counterForImages = 1
let leo = $("#Leo")
async function delay(ms) {
  // return await for better async stack trace support in case of errors.
  return await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function lol (fun) {
  var fadingIn = window.setInterval(function(){
    leo.css("opacity", Number(leo.css("opacity"))+0.02)
    if (leo.css("opacity") == 1) {
      clearInterval(fadingIn)
    }
  }, 50)
  await delay(5000)
  var fadingOut = window.setInterval(function(){
    leo.css("opacity", Number(leo.css("opacity"))-0.02)
    if (leo.css("opacity") == 0) {
      clearInterval(fadingOut)
    }
  }, 50)
  await delay(5000)
  leo.attr("src", "assets/Leo" + counterForImages%3 + ".png")
  if (counterForImages%3 == 0) {
    leo.css("width", "200px")
    leo.css("left", "85%")
  } else if (counterForImages%3 == 1) {
    leo.css("width", "400px")
    leo.css("left", "80%")
  } else if (counterForImages%3 == 2) {
    leo.css("width", "180px")
    leo.css("left", "85%")
  }
  counterForImages++
  fun(lol)
}

lol(lol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you are using jQuery, not pure JavaScript.

If I understand what you're doing, this might work:

```
var image_data=[[200,85], [400,80], [180,85]];
var counterForImages=0, leo=$('#leo');
function rotateImage() {
  counterForImages=counterForImages%3;
  leo.css({
    opacity:0,
    width:image_data[counterForImages][0]+'px',
    left:image_data[counterForImage][1]+'%'
  });
  leo.attr('src', 'assets/Leo' + counterForImages + '.png');
  leo.animate({opacity:1}, 5000, ()=>{
    leo.animate({opacity:0}, 5000, ()=>{
      counterForImages++;
      rotateImage();
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: thank you, i guess maximum recursion depth with animate doesn't work right?